# What is this insect in India?

Tags: species-identification

I found this insect today in front of my room.

I am just curious to know what kind of insect it is? And, is it poisonous?

**Location: India**

[image]

Comment: Where do you live? It may help narrow the possibilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a black Cricket .

Crickets, (family **Gryllidae**) are related to the Grasshoppers Family.

It should have grasshopper like hind legs .
Crickets usually emit  noise from its body.

Comment: I can't tell what its legs look like from that image, it's kind of blurry. But I think it's either a type of cricket or cockroach. If those are wings at the bottom of the insect I'd lean towards cockroach. And I swear I remember crickets and cockroaches as both being orthoptera, but now cockroaches are grouped with termites? When did that happen?

Comment: @user137 crickets were never grouped with cockroaches as far as I'm aware. Some scientists used to group together mantises, orthopterans, cockroaches, and stick insects together.